# Android PackageStats gives always zero

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers, android-storage

I'm trying to get the size occupied by my application package. Every application has one location in the internal/external storage.

I want to calculate the size of the following directory, how can I do that?
I know I can use [StorageStateManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/StorageStatsManager.html) on and above Oreo (API 26) devices, but how can I achieve this before oreo devices.

Application Directory : `/Android/data/myapplicationpackage`

I'm trying to use [PackageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageStats.html) but It's giving me always zero. What's the actual way to use this code?

I used the following code and it gives me all zero.

```
PackageStats stats = new PackageStats(context.getPackageName());
    long codeSize  = stats.codeSize + stats.externalCodeSize;
    long dataSize  = stats.dataSize + stats.externalDataSize;
    long cacheSize = stats.cacheSize + stats.externalCacheSize;
    long appSize   = codeSize + dataSize + cacheSize;
```

Answer (score 11):

> PackageStats stats = new PackageStats(context.getPackageName());

It will only creates the packagestats object. As [from the source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageStats.java), the constructor will do initializing the fields,

```
 public PackageStats(String pkgName) {
        packageName = pkgName;
        userHandle = UserHandle.myUserId();
    }
```

**for api<26,**

You need to use **`IPackageStatsObserver.aidl`** and have to invoke **`getPackageSizeInfo`** method by *reflection*.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
    "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.yourpackage",
    new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
            throws RemoteException {

            //here the pStats has all the details of the package
        }
    });
```

Here is the [complete solution](http://allandroidprojects.blogspot.in/2016/06/android-get-cache-size-data-size-apk.html) for it. It works great.

**from api 26**,

The `getPackageSizeInfo` method is deprecated.

You can use this code,

```
 @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            final StorageStatsManager storageStatsManager = (StorageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            final StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
            try {
                        ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagename, 0);
                        StorageStats storageStats = storageStatsManager.queryStatsForUid(ai.storageUuid, info.uid);
                        cacheSize =storageStats.getCacheBytes();
                        dataSize =storageStats.getDataBytes();
                        apkSize =storageStats.getAppBytes();
                        size+=info.cacheSize;
                } catch (Exception e) {}
```

But to use this code, You need **USAGE ACCESS PERMISSION** .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for the answer without reflection, you can't rely on the reflection for the production code.
Thanks for clarifying the concept of `PackageStats`, I believe android document is not good for this class.

Comment: When I was trying to get package size , I searched a lot. I didn't get any official solution for it.

Comment: @JyotiJK thanks for your code, but where the `storageManager` variable used and how can we get an `info.uid`? Thanks.

Comment: @Acuna sorry I just pasted my project code. Here info.uid is your application uid. **getApplicationInfo().uid**

Comment: And yes, what is the `USAGE ACCESS PERMISSION`? Is it `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`?

Comment: yup, You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153556/8867002)