# Is there any alternate way to find cache size for Pie?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class cachePackState : IPackageStatsObserver.Stub()
```

not working in pie kotlin android code

Comment: related: [Android PackageStats gives always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606077/android-packagestats-gives-always-zero)